# How to curve text upward?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, text-object

I'm attempting to create curved text at the bottom part of a circle. I am able to successfully create curved text around the circle and position it at the top of the circle and center it. But what I also need is to duplicate this same text at the bottom part of the circle while keeping the text readable without being upside down.

As the text is created it takes the two outside ends of the text string and bends then around the circle creating an arc with the CENTER of the text string being extended up and the ENDS extended down if viewed in top view mode.

I also need to create an additional arc of text where the ends of the string are extended up so I can then position it at the bottom of the circle and still read from the same perspective.

I can rotate the text around the circle but when it's rotated the bottom of the circle the writing is upside down. I've searched but can not find a solution for the problem.

Comment: Can you add some images to your question, like a picture of what you want to achieve or screenshots of what you have so far. I assume you are using the curve modifier in your text object. The resulting position of the deformation depends on a number of factors like relative position and rotation between objects, curve origin point and modifier settings. Try playing with the direction buttons in your curve modifier. If noone answers in the meantime I'll try to post a more complete answer later later when I'm at the computer.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Sticking to a specific question will help, and adding images will help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's pretty simple to set up text at the bottom of the circle. Just duplicate the top text and circle curve.

[image][image]

Then move the text down until it fits the inside of the bottom of the circle. At this point the text will be in the right place but will be reversed. You just need to scale with -1 on the axis the text is on (x axis in my screenshot).

[image]

Comment: No problem Darryl, please mark my solution as accepted if it answers your question fully. Cheers.

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as correct if it solved your problem, or at least up-vote it if it helped your.